# Function in jQuery to manipulate a group of ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to create a jQuery function with which I can access to certain elements and manipulate them. So far I was only able to access to certain ids and manipulate them but I don't know how to program a function which just takes a string as a parameter and I can basically reuse this function for all elements I want to manipulate.

This is what I have so far:

```javascript
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

// id for the trigger
var trigger = jQuery('#acf-use_right_column');

if (jQuery(trigger).length) {
    // list of ids to be manipulated
    var ids = jQuery('#acf-content_right_column, #acf-show_content, #acf-show_news, #acf-news_header, #acf-show_newsletter_form');
        // toggle element on click to hide/show 
        trigger.find('input:checkbox').click(function() {
            ids.toggle();
        });
        // hide id in dependence of the state of the checkbox
        trigger.find('input:checkbox').each(function(){
            // if checkbox not checked
            if(!jQuery(this).attr('checked')){ 
                ids.hide();
            }
        });     

}

});
```

It allows me to manipulate a group of ids. 
So if I want to manipulate another group of ids in my document I would have to write the same code again. 
Can anybody tell me how to create a function from this code which accepts parameters?
I would like to just call the functions with the ids I want to manipulate as a parameter string for the function. 
Any ideas?

Comment: So you want to use an array of IDs instead of `'#acf-content_right_column, #acf-show_content, #acf-show_news, #acf-news_header, #acf-show_newsletter_form'`?

Comment: yes, I want to use an array ... because I have certain collection of ids and I basically want to 'resuse' the code without having to adapt it for other ids. A function/plugin will allow me to do that but I can't find a solution because it is to complicated for me. I tried it but my head was smoking. :))

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a way to turn array of IDs into an ID selector that 
jQuery will understand. This isn't terribly difficult if you know 
your way around jQuery.

```
// Name it whatever you want, 'pancakes' is my 'foo'.
function pancakes(trigger, ids) {
    trigger = $('#' + trigger);
    // `trigger` is a jQuery object already so you don't have to
    // `jQuery(trigger)` here
    if(trigger.length) {
        // This turns `['a','b','c']` into `$('#a,#b,#c')`, the $.map adds the
        // `'#'` prefix to each element of the `ids` array and produces another
        // array with the prefixed `ids`; the `join` sticks the elements of the
        // new array together into a multiple selector.
        ids = $($.map(ids, function(id) { return '#' + id }).join(','));

        // And the rest is as you had it...
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
pancakes(
    'act-use_right_column',
    ['acf-content_right_column', 'acf-show_content', 'acf-show_news', 'acf-news_header', 'acf-show_newsletter_form']
);
```

References:

- [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [Multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Comment: :) Thank you very much ... I will try this out today or tomorrow and give some feedback.

Comment: This is totally amazing. 
It works like a charm and I have the feeling that it is quite efficient because the code is so short. I am using it to simplify the Wordpress Admin Interface (built on a plugin named 'Advanced Custom Fields'). With this here I can hide and show fields based on the state of checkboxes. It makes my work on the interface much easier.

Answer (score 1):

is a lot simpler than you think, you can use `javascript` variables inside your function,

```
 function myNewFunction(parameter1,parameter2){

      var trigger = jQuery(parameter1);
      if (jQuery(trigger).length) {
           // list of ids to be manipulated
           var ids = jQuery(parameter1+', '+parameter2+'_content, '+parameter2+'_news, '+parameter2+'_header, '+parameter2+'_newsletter_form');
           // toggle element on click to hide/show 
           trigger.find('input:checkbox').click(function() {
                ids.toggle();
           });
           // hide id in dependence of the state of the checkbox
           trigger.find('input:checkbox').each(function(){
           // if checkbox not checked
           if(!jQuery(this).attr('checked')){ 
               ids.hide();
           }
       });     
     }
 }

 myNewFunction('#acf-use_right_column','#acf-show');
```

You can even use an array of strings and use something like

```
 ...
 compare = ids.lenght-1
 for (var key in idArray){
     if(key!=compare){
        string=string+idArray[key]+', '
     }else{
        string=string+idArray[key]
     }
 }
 ids = jQuery(string)
 ...

 idArray = new Array('#id1','#id2','#id3','#id4')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I will try this out today or tomorrow and give feedback. :)

Comment: That is pretty awesome. I have just build a very useful function with that in minutes. I am starting to understand the principle.

Answer (score 0):

please see the code below, It may not be correct but you can use the appraoch

```
var manipulate=function(tiggerobj, arrayofobj){

// step1 :- use parameter1 fpr id for the trigger
var trigger = jQuery(tiggerobj);

if (jQuery(trigger).length) {
    // list of ids to be manipulated
var ids=new Array();
//step2 :-accumaltae all the ids
for (var ob in arrayofobj){

id.push(jQuery(arrayofobj(ob)));
}


        //step3- toggle element on click to hide/show 
        trigger.find('input:checkbox').click(function() {
            ids.toggle();
        });
        // hide id in dependence of the state of the checkbox
        trigger.find('input:checkbox').each(function(){
            // if checkbox not checked
            if(!jQuery(this).attr('checked')){ 
                ids.hide();
            }
        });     

}

}
```

Than call this manipulate function where you need

Comment: That looks nice but honestly my jquery skills are not enough to get this to work. I don't even really understand what this script is doing. ;)

Comment: After reading it a bit longer and having adapted the other examples here I am starting to understand your function. The other solutions where somehow easier for me to comprehend and to adapt. 
Thanks again.